# Animate hidden property on UILabels in UIStackView causes different animations

Tags: ios, animation, uistackview, animatewithduration

`UIStackView` makes it really easy to create a nice animation using the hidden property of a UIView. I have two `UIStackViews` each with `UILabels` in the `arrangedSubviews` and when I add a new `UILabel` to a `UIStackView`, it should present it with an animation of the label appearing at the correct index, pushing the labels above and below it.

This effect is very easy to do using `UIStackViews`:

```
descriptionLabel.hidden = true 

let count = descriptionStack.arrangedSubviews.count
descriptionStack.insertArrangedSubview(expenseLabel.descriptionLabel, atIndex: count - 1)

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
  descriptionLabel.hidden = false
}
```

I want to do this effect simultaneously for two different `UIStackViews`, but this causes some weird behaviour, where one is animated correctly while the other drops in from the top of the view.
Assuming that the above code can be repeated for some other view and create the same animation:

```
descriptionLabel.hidden = true 
costLabel.hidden = true

let count = descriptionStack.arrangedSubviews.count
descriptionStack.insertArrangedSubview(expenseLabel.descriptionLabel, atIndex: count - 1)
costStack.insertArrangedSubview(expenseLabel.costLabel, atIndex: count - 1)

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
  descriptionLabel.hidden = false
  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
    costLabel.hidden = false
  }
}
```

In this example, the `costLabel` is animated correctly, while `descriptionLabel` drops in from the top of the `UIStackView`. Reversing the order causes the `costLabel` to drop in and `descriptionLabel` to animate correctly.

I've tried variations of this animation code e.g. not nesting the animations and using `UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration`.

Doing it as below, causes the `costLabel` to drop in and the `descriptionLabel` to animate correctly:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
  descriptionLabel.hidden = false
}

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
  costLabel.hidden = false
}
```

I cannot figure out why the animations are always different from each other. How do I animate both labels simultaneously and having the effect where they appear at the correct index, pushing the labels above and below?

Answer (score 6):

I have exactly the same problem. I found out that setting the `Content Mode` property of the `UILabel` seems to change the way the `UIView` animation is performed. In my case I wanted to achieve an animation from top to bottom. The default animation was a slide in from left combined with a resize. Setting Content Mode to `Top` worked for me.

Maybe that helps.

Comment: Changing the `Content Mode` definitely has an effect on how the `UILabel` is animated, but it doesn't seem very consistent. Setting it to  `.Left` makes the label "drop down" but setting it to  `.Right` makes it appear from the left side of the view.

It does at least look better appearing from the side, thanks!